# Firebase Google users not showing in Firebase Console Authentication

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Using Firebase Google Auth, when a user logs in successfully with their google account, they are not showing on our Firebase Console Authentication->Users screen.  Only email/password users are showing up there.

Is there something extra that needs to be done to see the Google Auth users?

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: no need to extra steps if your authentication works all good

Comment: OAuth users (such as Google) will only show in the Firebase console after you sign them into Firebase by calling `signInWithCredential()`. Until that call they may have signed in with Google, but they have not signed in to Firebase.

Comment: Indeed, this was the issue.  I was not calling signInWithCredential() anywhere and it was successfully signing into Google, but not through to Firebase.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As indicated by Frank, to fully sign into Firebase the call to signInWithCredential() was needed.  After implementing this functionality, users signing in with Google showed up in the Firebase console.

Comment: how can I implement this `signInWithCredential()` with google connect? thanks

Comment: const googleCredential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(response.idToken);
          firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(googleCredential)
          .then(user => {

});

Answer (score 5):

In Flutter, besides GoogleSignIn, you also need to install firebase_auth package.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth#-installing-tab-

```
https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = (await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}

...

_handleSignIn()
    .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: FirebaseUser is deprecated, use User instead!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below steps:

- Trigger the Google Authentication flow.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
```

- Obtain the auth details from the request.

```
final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;
```

- Create a new credential

```
final GoogleAuthCredential googleCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
```

- Sign in to Firebase with the Google [UserCredential]

```
final UserCredential googleUserCredential =
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(googleCredential);
```

That's it !!